# How to make EC2 instance in private subnet accessible from the internet? (as in being able to visit the website)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, private-subnet

I know that one way is to use a load balancer in a public subnet, but for a development server we wouldn't need a load balancer. Is there an alternative option that would allow an application in a private subnet to be reachable from the internet?

If not, then would the best option be to just leave the development server in a public subnet? The database instances would still be in a private subnet.

Comment: You need to have an [internet gateway](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28778970/aws-elastic-ip-network-vpc-is-not-attached-to-any-internet-gateway/28779019#28779019) and then you can assign an elastic IP to the instance.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

An Amazon EC2 instance in a **private subnet** will *never* be directly reachable from the Internet, even if it has a public IP address. This is because a private subnet does not have a Route Table entry that connects the subnet to an Internet Gateway. This is intentional and desired.

So, your options are:

- Put your instance in a **Public Subnet** instead of a Private Subnet, or
- Create a **VPN connection** to the VPC so you can communicate with resources in the VPC, including the private subnet, or
- Connect to an instance in the Public Subnet and use **Port Forwarding** to then obtain a connection with the private instance (see below), or
- Use a **Load Balancer** or Proxy in the Public Subnet to forward traffic to the private subnet (one benefit is that it mimics the production setup)

Port Forwarding is a common technique to provide private connectivity to a resource that is not directly accessible. For example:

- `Public-Instance` in the public subnet
- `Private-Instance` in the private subnet
- SSH into `Public-Instance` with port forwarding, which then establishes a connection to `Private-Instance`
- Access resources on your local machine and it will actually forward the request to `Private-Instance`

A sample connection string would be:

```
ssh -i pemfile ec2-user@public-instance -L 8000:private-instance:80
```

Any request sent to your local computer's port 8000 would be forwarded to `Public-Instance`, which would then forward the request to `private-instance:80`. This will continue as long as the SSH session is in place.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed response! I think it might be a good idea to re-evaluate my thought that the application should be  in a private subnet. Would having the EC2 instance in a public subnet with a security group that only allowed HTTP, HTTPS, and SSH (restricted to bastion host security group) be effectively different from having the EC2 instance in a private subnet with HTTP traffic routed through a proxy server in a public subnet?

Comment: I had originally considered using a load balancer for the development server EC2 instance as well because it would do exactly what I need, but I thought I surely must be overlooking something if I'm setting up a load balancer that is directing traffic to a single target group with only a single instance in it. It seemed like more of a work around in my mind. Am I looking at that in the wrong way? Is it a fairly commonplace thing to do?

Comment: You would be perfectly okay never using private subnets (with an exception for allowing Lambda to access VPC resources _and_ the Internet). This is an old-fashioned concept that relates to the way networking equipment used to enforce security at the subnet-level. You can instead use Security Groups to enforce security at the instance-level. However, some security folks still like to use private subnets as an additional layer of security. For your dev resources, you should also lock-down the security groups to only _your_ IP range, so nobody else can access them.

Comment: That makes perfect sense. I will  go ahead and set it up in a public subnet and use the security group then (and also restrict the IP range for SSH). Thank you once more for all of your insight, it has been really helpful!

Comment: @JohnRotenstein - What exactly restricts a request to a Private Subnet EC2 instance if it has a public IP. Because request may arrive at VPC, VPC has IGW, IGW can translate Public IP to Private IP, and can redirect request to ec2 in private subnet. Here, I am unable to understand the lookup in route table for an inbound request.

Comment: @Ankush By definition, a private subnet does not have a Route Table entry that points to an Internet Gateway. Therefore, the Internet Gateway cannot communicate with resources in there private subnet.